How to decode Cbox HEX format to Go struct
Could Anyone help to decode the Cbor Hex format to a struct in Go?
I've tried to define struct like the following but it seems not to be working
package main

import (
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/fxamacker/cbor/v2"
)

// Define the structs that match the CBOR structure

type Field struct {
    Bytes      *string    `cbor:"bytes,omitempty"`
    Int        *int64     `cbor:"int,omitempty"`
    Constructor *int      `cbor:"constructor,omitempty"`
    Fields     []Field    `cbor:"fields,omitempty"`
}

type Datum struct {
    Constructor int     `cbor:"constructor"`
    Fields      []Field `cbor:"fields"`
}

func main() {
    // The CBOR hex string to decode
    cborHex := "d8799f581c8e76c60dd3cbccdf8af264e560686078f05345d96d90c4af19c6c4f69f9f4040ff9f581c016be5325fd988fea98ad422fcfd53e5352cacfced5c106a932a35a44342544effff1b00000117fc424de018961896d8799fd8799f581cc7eb8762b9718b6975e3e0676d3e7f61e926258f4b8a83077ddea504ffff001a23ec0b80ff"

    // Decode the hex string into bytes
    cborData, err := hex.DecodeString(cborHex)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to decode hex: %v", err)
    }

    // Unmarshal the CBOR data into a Datum struct
    var datum Datum
    err = cbor.Unmarshal(cborData, &datum)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to unmarshal CBOR data: %v", err)
    }

    // Print the decoded Datum
    fmt.Printf("Decoded Datum: %+v\n", datum)
}

For example Cbor Hex output
https://cardanoscan.io/datumInspector?datum=d8799f581c8e76c60dd3cbccdf8af264e560686078f05345d96d90c4af19c6c4f69f9f4040ff9f581c016be5325fd988fea98ad422fcfd53e5352cacfced5c106a932a35a44342544effff1b00000117fc424de018961896d8799fd8799f581cc7eb8762b9718b6975e3e0676d3e7f61e926258f4b8a83077ddea504ffff001a23ec0b80ff
Thank you
